# EF7 value of foreign key not being saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using EF7 and I have three entities:

```
class A {
    public int Id;
    public B B;
}


class B {
    public int Id;
    public string SomeValue;
    public virtual IEnumerable<C> C;
}

public class C {
    public int Id;
    public string SomeValue;
    public virtual B B;
}
```

The automatically generated migration seems fine, and a foreign key is added from C to B.
However when I do the following, no value is assigned to the foreign key in the database:

```
var a = _dbContext.A.Single(x => x.Id == id);
a.B = new B {
    SomeValue = "SomeValue";
    C = listOfC;
};
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The actual values of C are stored in the corresponding table, but as the foreign key is not saved I can no longer retrieve it in relation to B.

Is EF7 not able to properly do nested inserts? Is there some way to work around this?

**Edit:**
Explicitly declaring the foreign key makes it not nullable, which means the inserts fail ("bad foreign key constraint") instead.

Comment: Please update your example to include the Actual properties of the Class, from your definition there is no Id define, nor the value for the foreign key Id,

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right there is no property for the foreign key in the entity - EF automatically generates this. I have tried explicitly declaring it in the entity aswell, but this changes absolutely nothing.

Comment: Well this is not absolutely true, explicitly declaring the foreign key makes it not nullable, meaning that inserts fail because the database complains about the missing value of the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the IEnumerable in B to ICollection resolves the issue:

```
class B {
    public int Id;
    public string SomeValue;
    public virtual ICollection<C> C;
}
```